# How can a negative charge be applied to items in d3v4?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm working with d3 version 4 in an Angular 4 application. I've got d3 working just fine as I can add items to the screen, but I can't seem to understand how to get the forces to be applied appropriately.

I've looked at a number of excellent examples by [Jim Vallandingham](http://vallandingham.me/) and [Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock).

Here is the bubble chart code I currently have. I'm utilizing d3v4, Angular4 and Typescript. The full code sample can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/PdUi/ng-d3v4-components/tree/add-bubble-chart). Created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZs12xRHgVGUMUyGGaXQ?p=preview) as well.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Inject, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { select } from 'd3-selection';
import { scaleOrdinal, scalePow } from 'd3-scale';
import { forceSimulation, forceManyBody, forceX, forceY } from 'd3-force';
import { max } from 'd3-array';
import { rgb } from 'd3-color';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('bubble') bubble;
  @Input() rawData: { id: string, value: number }[] = [];

  private words: string[] = [RANDOM_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS_EXCLUDED_HERE_FOR_BREVITY];
  private element: ElementRef;

  private forceStrength = 0.03;
  private bubbles: any = {};

  private center: { x: number, y: number };

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      const id = this.words[Math.ceil(Math.random() * this.words.length)];
      const value = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);
      this.rawData.push({ id: id, value: value})
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.bubble.nativeElement;
    const elementStyles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element);
    const textColor = elementStyles.color;
    const backgroundColor = elementStyles.backgroundColor;

    const height = element.offsetHeight;
    const width = element.offsetWidth;
    this.center = { x: width / 2, y: height / 2 };

    const fillColor = scaleOrdinal().domain(['small', 'medium', 'large'])
                                    .range(['#8c4da1', '#3f7fb0', '#e69057']);

    const svg = select(element).append('svg')
                                 .attr('width', width)
                                 .attr('height', height);

    const container = svg.append('rect')
                           .attr('fill', backgroundColor)
                           .attr('width', width)
                           .attr('height', height);

    const nodes = this.createNodes(this.rawData, width, height);
    this.bubbles = svg.selectAll('.bubble')
                      .data(nodes, (d: { id: string }) => d.id);

    const bubblesE = this.bubbles.enter()
                            .append('circle')
                              .classed('bubble', true)
                              .attr('r', (d: { radius: number }) => d.radius)
                              .attr('fill', (d: { name: string }) => fillColor(d.name))
                              .attr('stroke', (d: { name: string }) => rgb(<any>fillColor(d.name)).darker())
                              .attr('stroke-width', 2);

    this.bubbles = this.bubbles.merge(bubblesE);

    svg.selectAll('text')
       .data(nodes)
       .enter()
       .append('text')
         .text((d) => d.name)
         .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
         .attr('y', (d) => d.y)
         .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
         .attr('fill', textColor);

    const simulation = forceSimulation().velocityDecay(0.2)
                                        .force('x', forceX().strength(this.forceStrength).x(this.center.x))
                                        .force('y', forceY().strength(this.forceStrength).y(this.center.y))
                                        .force('charge', forceManyBody().strength((d: any) => -Math.pow(d.radius, 2.0) * this.forceStrength))
                                        .on('tick', this.ticked.apply(this))
                                        .nodes(nodes);
  }

  charge(d: { radius: number }) {
    return -Math.pow(d.radius, 2.0) * this.forceStrength;
  }

  ticked() {
    this.bubbles.attr('cx', (d) => d.x)
                .attr('cy', (d) => d.y);
  }

  createNodes(rawData: { id: string, value: number }[], maxWidth: number, maxHeight: number): { id: string, radius: number, value: number, name: string, x: number, y: number}[] {
    const maxAmount = max(rawData, (d) => +d.value);

    const radiusScale = scalePow().exponent(0.5)
                                  .range([2, 85])
                                  .domain([0, maxAmount]);

    const myNodes = rawData.map((d) => {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        radius: radiusScale(+d.value),
        value: +d.value,
        name: d.id,
        x: Math.random() * maxWidth,
        y: Math.random() * maxHeight
      };
    });

    myNodes.sort(function (a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

    return myNodes;
  }
}
```

The forces are definitely being applied, but in most of the examples I'm looking at(that use almost identical forces) the bubbles rarely overlap. Mine seem to overlap a lot which obscures the text and causes the graphic to lose a lot of its readability.
[image: Screenshot]

**How can I get the forces to be applied in a way that they bubbles will repel each other sufficiently so there will be minimal overlap?** I've tried toying with a lot of the values in the code, but can't seem to find the correct combinations.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a collide force. Create a working version (not that GitHub link) and we can edit it for you.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZs12xRHgVGUMUyGGaXQ?p=preview)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried looking into forceCollide, found a very interesting [tutorial](www.puzzlr.org/force-directed-graph-collision-forces/) and tried to apply its principles to my Plunker, but still without luck, if you could provide any more direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @[Gerardo Furtado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado), the simulation was missing a forceCollide

```
    this.simulation = forceSimulation(this.data)
                        .alphaDecay(0.075)
                        .force('center', forceCenter(this.containerWidth / 2, this.containerHeight / 2))
                        .force('repulsion', forceManyBody().strength(2))
                        .force('collide', forceCollide((datum, index, groups) => this.radiusScale(datum.relativeWeight)))
.on('tick', this.tick.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5W9LF623Wh5S7EWPtKFH?p=preview) with the solution.

You have to add one behaviour simulation to each node.

- Declare it: `public simulation: any;`
- start it within constructor:

`this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
                     .force("center", d3.forceCenter(this.width / 2, this.height / 2));`

> observe that here is where you have to play with the parameters until
>   you get a satisfactory setup.

- apply simulation during chart creation.

`this.simulation
     .nodes(nodes)
     .on("tick", ()=>{node.attr("transform", this.positionNode);});`

- add the function to repositioning yours nodes:

  `private positionNode(d: any) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }`

Everything together should give the effect that you desire, now is up to you setup the variables.

Comment: Thank you, but I fail to see how this answers the question. The plunker you sent looks the same as the one I created. I've been playing with the forceCenter and 'tick' parameters without seeing anything change regarding the overlap of the bubbles. I'm not sure what these parameters represent or in which direction I should be moving them. I thought a negative charge force was a repulsion of sorts.

Comment: Observe the elements that I cited in the answer inside the file app/app.component.ts. Play with the attributes that I cited above and there might be changes.